# Passing a model method's output to its controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I've defined this method in my Track model

```
def random_number
    max = Article.maximum(:id)
    id = rand(1..max)
    return id
end
```

and am trying to pass it to the Tracks controller to render another classes object in the tracks controller's index view like so:

```
def index
  @tracks = Track.all
  id = Track.random_number
  @random = Article.find_by_id(id)
end
```

Yet keep getting a NoMethodError "undefined method `random_number' for #".

Any tips on how to render this correctly?

Thanks!!

Comment: `random_number` can be refactored down to one line: `rand 1..Article.maximum(:id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling it like it were a class method. Add `self` to the method an you are good to go.

```
def self.random_number
```

The way it is now, you can only access the method using an instance of the Track class.

```
@track = Track.new
@track.random_number
```